# Angular 5 add, remove row on click buttons

Tags: angular, typescript

In angular 5 I want to add new row and remove new row button so that thy will add a new row to the table and delete the row when click on the buttons. But when I am trying this code its showing error like

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined
```

Here is what I have tries

event-create.component.html looks like this

```
<div class="container col-md-12">
  <h1 class="page-header">Create Event</h1>
  <form [formGroup] = "form" (ngSubmit)="onEventSubmit()">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="eventname">Event Name</label>
      <div class='form-group'>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Event Name" formControlName="eventname">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="eventdesc">Event Description</label>
      <div class='form-group'>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Event Description" formControlName="eventdesc">
      </div>
    </div>

    <h4>Event Package</h4>
    <hr>
    <div class="row" formGroupName="itemRows">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="packagename">Package Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Package Name" name="packagename" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="packageprice">Package Price</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Package Price" name="packageprice" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="packagelimit">Max Purchase Limit</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="packagelimit" autocomplete="off" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <br/>
        <input type="button" (click)="addPackageRow()" class="btn btn-md btn-success" value="Add New Package" name="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">

  </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

event-create.component.ts looks like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormControlName } from '@angular/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-event-create',
  templateUrl: './event-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event-create.component.css']
})
export class EventCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  form :  FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder : FormBuilder,
    ) { this.createEventForm(); }

  createEventForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      eventname: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(5)
      ])],
      eventdesc: ['', Validators.required],
      packagename: ['',],
      packageprice: ['',],
      packagelimit: ['',]
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        itemRows: this.formBuilder.array([this.initItemRows()])
      });
  }

  initItemRows() {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
            itemname: ['']
        });
    }

  public addPackageRow() {
    console.log(this.form);
     // const control = this.form.controls['itemRows'];
    // control.push(this.initItemRows());
  }

}
```

I don't know what is going wrong here. Can someone tell me how to make this work? Anu help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Comment: Where is `errors` property in your code?

Comment: I have added the property in createEventForm() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this component for more info on the same [**`GIT-LINK`**](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/blob/master/src/app/reactive/reactive.component.ts#L63).

Live Example for the same [**`check the Address in the form`**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive)

**gist**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = new FormGroup({
      addresses: new FormArray([
        this.initAddress(), 
      ])
    });

 initAddress(){
    return new FormGroup({
      street : new FormControl(''),
      postcode : new FormControl('')
    });
  }

  addAddress(){
    const control = <FormArray>this.user.controls['addresses'];
    control.push(this.initAddress());
  }

  removeAddress(i: number){
    const control = <FormArray>this.user.controls['addresses'];
    control.removeAt(i);
  }
```

Comment: Can you answer my another question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48761002/angular-5-not-showing-user-entered-values-from-formarray