# How to use an object as the default value in Angular FormControl (without using a reference)?

Tags: angular

I am creating a select element, and want to set an object as the default value when the application starts.
In my example I have a list of animals, and a FormControl used in an HTML template.
I tried adding an object (not a reference to an object) directly to the formControl like this:

`animalControl = new FormControl({name:'Dog', sound: 'Woof!'}, [Validators.required]); // this does not work`

This does not work. However, referencing an object from the actual list works, like this:

`this.animalControl.setValue(this.animals[1]); // this works`

Is there another way of setting a value to the formControl without having to find the correct reference, only passing an object to it instead?

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-object-default-select?file=app/select-hint-error-example.ts

TS:

```
 export class SelectHintErrorExample {
  animalControl = new FormControl({name:'Dog', sound: 'Woof!'}, [Validators.required]); // this does not work

  animals = [
    {name: 'Dog', sound: 'Woof!'},
    {name: 'Cat', sound: 'Meow!'},
    {name: 'Cow', sound: 'Moo!'},
    {name: 'Fox', sound: 'Wa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pow!'},
  ];
  constructor(){
    // this.animalControl.setValue(this.animals[1]); // this works
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite animal" [formControl]="animalControl" required>
    <mat-option>--</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let animal of animals" [value]="animal">
      {{animal.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="animalControl.hasError('required')">Please choose an animal</mat-error>
  <mat-hint>{{animalControl.value?.sound}}</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create a reference, you can use `compareWith` in your select, just like on any other `select` tag:

```
<mat-select [compareWith]="compareAnimals" ...
```

and TS:

```
compareAnimals(a1: any, a2: any): boolean {
  return a1 && a2 ? a1.name === a2.name : a1 === a2;
}
```

Your StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-object-default-select-ervu6r?file=app%2Fselect-hint-error-example.ts

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will give it a try next week. I am just concerned about efficiency. Will the ‘compareAnimals’ method run after each change cycle? In that case it might be better to find the reference once after all.

Answer (score 0):

Use FormBuilder https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#introduction-to-formbuilder. You must decided that you want to use a FormArray or not

```
//If a only animal
createForm(data:any)
{
  this.animalcontrol=this.fb.group({
      name: [data.name?data.name:'',Validators.Required],
      sound:[data.sound=data.sound:'']
    });
}
```

if you want use a formArray, check too [Angular 5 populate data with FormArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781442/angular-5-populate-data-with-formarray/48782162#48782162)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This approach means that my `animalcontrol` must be of type `FormGroup`, I want it to be of type `FormControl`. Also, if I have an object with a lot more properties, would I still need to copy all of them? Isn't it an approach to pass the object itself, instead of copying it?