# Angular 8- How to bind FormControlName as a object to view

Tags: angular, form-control

I want to patch an object of formControl to HTML but I get {object object}. How can I patch this object as json data in HTML? I want to show {authors: 'James'} in my HTML.
Here is my code

```
TS file:
form = this.formBuilder.group({
 key: [{authors: 'James'}]
})

HTML file:
<mat-form-field>
   <textarea matInput formControlName="key"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here is my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wnk3fx

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz with your example?

Comment: what is your desired output? Like to show { author:James} in the input field or just james? and why do you want to keep it as object?

Comment: @Supercool.yes I want to show {authors: James}

Comment: @Supercool.my full key like: 
key: [{authors: 'James'},
{year:'2020'}] so user can see detail of a book in one row

Comment: Just include it in quotes like ['{authors: 'James'}']

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822940/how-to-use-an-object-as-the-default-value-in-angular-formcontrol-without-using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want display {authors: 'James'} change to this

```
firstName: ["{authors: 'James'}", Validators.required],
```

Live [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-becovs)

Comment: I edited my question, my formControlName is key and value is {authors: 'James'}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is it that you exactly want?

Here are a few options:

`firstName: [{authors: 'James'}, Validators.required]` to

`firstName: ['James', Validators.required]`

`firstName: ['authors: James', Validators.required]`

`firstName: ['{authors: 'James'}', Validators.required]`

and you'll get the name. Since `{authors: 'James'}` is an object the `input` element prints `[object Object]`

Comment: I want to show {authors:'James'} in my HTML not only firstName